# Full text PDF search application with React JS

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I'm developing a side project using ReactJS & React Native which lists the matching PDF files from a network location based on user "full text" search. I have used windows search service with ASP.NET mvc for the same project.

Looking for guidance to implement the same app using react, react-native with more separation of concerns and platform independent (not relying on windows search service). Sorry if this is a vague question. appreciate if get any guidance here.

Comment: This is way too vague to adequately answer. Voted to close. Please come back when you have specific hard problems you are trying to solve. :) Please see "How to ask a question" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sure. make sense. i will do that. thank you @jered